# Spring boot connect oracle 19c database: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/***] threw exception

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, oracle19c

I am building a Spring MVC WebApp.I am using oracle database 19 with hr sample database.An error occurred while testing MyController.I am designing and configuring this way below:

```
package com.example.testoracle.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "HIRE_DATE")
    private Date hireDate;

    @Column(name = "JOB_ID")
    private String jobId;

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private int salary;

    @Column(name = "COMMISSION_PCT")
    private int commissionPct;

    @Column(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private int managerId;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private int departmentId;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int employeeId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber, Date hireDate, String jobId, int salary, int commissionPct, int managerId, int departmentId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.commissionPct = commissionPct;
        this.managerId = managerId;
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Date getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }

    public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }

    public String getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }

    public void setJobId(String jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getCommissionPct() {
        return commissionPct;
    }

    public void setCommissionPct(int commissionPct) {
        this.commissionPct = commissionPct;
    }

    public int getManagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    public void setManagerId(int managerId) {
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }

    public int getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "employeeId=" + employeeId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                ", hireDate='" + hireDate + '\'' +
                ", jobId='" + jobId + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                ", commissionPct=" + commissionPct +
                ", managerId=" + managerId +
                ", departmentId=" + departmentId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

controller:

```
package com.example.testoracle.controller;


import com.example.testoracle.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService service;

    @RequestMapping("/testoracle")
    public String getEmployees() {
        return service.getEmployees().toString();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.testoracle.repository;

import com.example.testoracle.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}
```

Service:

```
package com.example.testoracle.service;

import com.example.testoracle.model.Employee;
import com.example.testoracle.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repo;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Employee employee : repo.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(employee);
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Application

```
package com.example.testoracle;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.example.testoracle.repository"})
public class TestoracleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestoracleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@orclpdb?TNS_ADMIN=D:/OracleApp/WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home/network/admin
spring.datasource.username=hr
spring.datasource.password=hr
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-factory-class-name=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-q-l-for-validate-connection=select 1 from dual
spring.datasource.oracleucp.connection-pool-name=SpringBootPool
spring.datasource.oracleucp.min-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.oracleucp.max-pool-size=30
spring.datasource.oracleucp.initial-pool-size=15
logging.level.org.flowable.ldap.impl.LDAPUserQueryImpl=debug
```

Console Error

```
2023-06-29 10:31:01.878 ERROR 9808 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Null value was assigned to a property [class com.example.testoracle.model.Employee.commissionPct] of primitive type setter of com.example.testoracle.model.Employee.commissionPct; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property [class com.example.testoracle.model.Employee.commissionPct] of primitive type setter of com.example.testoracle.model.Employee.commissionPct] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.example.testoracle.model.Employee.commissionPct to null value
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:694) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntityFromEntityEntryLoadedState(TwoPhaseLoad.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1201) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1009) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:427) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy99.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.testoracle.service.EmployeeService.getEmployees(EmployeeService.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.testoracle.controller.MyController.getEmployees(MyController.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.76.jar:9.0.76]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I am taking reference from a youtube video but in the video, the code works but not in my case.

Please advise what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i fixed it, change int in nullable fields to Integer